# What does "quiet chord, a wide blue one" mean?

Tags: piano, chords

> She heard him out in the kitchen when the music stopped. She heard him
> go to the piano and plink with two fingers a tune whose name she did not
> know but which she had surely heard from the radio in Vicki’s room. ‘Tsk,’
> she said. ‘He would play that kind of stuff.’ She stepped into the passage,
> thinking herself safe and superior; but he struck one **quiet chord, a wide
> blue one**, a chord from the kind of music she knew nothing about and was
> too tight to play; she stood still, listening, and he left a silence, and then he
> resolved it.

I was reading a novel that I came across this: **quiet chord, a wide
blue one**

Does "quiet chord" mean "minor chord"?

And does "wide blue one" mean "keys that are blue and wider than other keys"?

Do keys in piano have different colors?

Source: This passage is from *The Children's Bach* by Helen Garner

Comment: Some people, with *synaesthesia*, see keys in different colours, smell them differently, taste them differently, and apply different feelings to them, etc. However, probably nothing to do with the quote. From whom?

Comment: Makes me think she's a classical player with little knowledge of jazz/blues. She recognises the resolution, but not the chord itself except to know it's bluesy & something she's never played. Even if she recognises the notes & the name of the chord they make, it's a genre outside her experience & comfort zone. Quiet just means 'not loud' but bluesy could contain major/minor tensions rarely heard in classical. Wide is just literally a long reach between the notes, which changes the 'flavour' of the chord.

Comment: I'm curious: What is the source of this passage?

Comment: I edited my question and added the source.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Judging from the rest of the passage my takeaway is it is simply a chord that is “bluesy”, having the quality of blues music, and by “wide” it probably indicates a chord played with several notes and the hands spread across the keyboard.

The person listening has a musical background and this type of chord seems to be something that is outside of her knowledge and comfort zone.

Comment: Lots of thanks, So can we say he played sad chord that was not loud and was quiet?

Comment: @ViserHashemi Not necessarily sad but something quiet that was different than what she is used to and surprised her. Also because she “felt superior” before he played it, it was something that was beyond what she thought he was capable of.

Comment: Thank you, and I have another question, Is "Tsk" a kind of music that she thinks that he is able to play only that kind of music?

Comment: I found this about Tsk : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsk_Tsk_Tsk

Comment: I would interpret “Tsk” to be literally the sound she made to voice her disapproval. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tsk

Comment: @ViserHashemi it is actually this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_click#In_English it is a phonetic spelling of a clicking sound made with the mouth to express disapproval like wabisabied said in a previous comment.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy you say “… and by “wide” it probably indicates a chord played with several notes and the hands spread across the keyboard.” But the passage says "She heard him go to the piano and plink with two fingers…” which would mean to me that it was only two notes played far apart.

Comment: @wabished, check it out again, he played one wide blue chord after the two finger plinking, after she felt superior and safe. Of course it’s literature and open to interpretation.

Comment: Lots of thanks for your comments, So "Tsk" mean: she made Tsk sound by her mouth to show her disapproval, and she thinks he is able to make only that kind of sound. am I right?

Comment: @ViserHashemi It was my pleasure and yes, you are right.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy Fair enough, it’s certainly open to interpretation, and probably not critical to the story, but the author only says he plinked the tune with two fingers, no mention of the wide chord being any more complex, only quiet and blue. From a genre she "was too tight to play,” which suggests to me that the chord is a bit dissonant, but in a more sophisticated way than she believed he, and the genre, were capable of. The ensuing silence and resolution seem to be what challenged her preconceived disapproval and legitimized the passage to her. At least that’s my take.

Comment: @wabisabied That’s an interesting take. To me the author made a point of distinguishing between plinking with two fingers and striking a wide blue chord which seems to have surprised and unnerved her. I don’t think that would’ve been done with just two fingers. It’s interesting how a small paragraph can generate this much discussion.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy Indeed!